# Displaying the lowest and higher number in Java after User Input?

Tags: java

How to to display the lowest and the higher number in Java? I know that I need use this variables: int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE; But I can't get it to work. :/ Any help?

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class LoopingNumbersUsingWhile {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How Many Numbers You Want To Enter: ");
    int total = kb.nextInt();
    int input = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int average=0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    while (input < total) {
        input++;

        System.out.println("Enter " + input + ". Operand: ");

                    sum += kb.nextInt();

   if (min >= sum) 
  { 
    min = sum;
  } 
if (max <= sum) 
  { 
  max = sum;
  } 



       average = ( sum ) / ( input);
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum + ".");
    System.out.println("The avg  " + average);
    System.out.println("The higher number  " + max);
    System.out.println("The the lowest number " + min);


   }
  }
```

Comment: Basically for min and max you compare with the wrong number `sum`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! But I still haven't figured out. I have tried all the thinks I can think of. Any other suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the next number into a temporary variable then add it to sum.

```
int temp = kb.nextInt();
sum+=temp
```

and do these checks against your temporary variable.

```
if (min >= temp) 
{ 
 min = temp;
} 
if (max <= temp) 
{ 
max = temp;
}
```

Comment: also `int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;` needs to be changed to `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`